# Binding of UriSource to BitmapImage not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, bitmapimage

My code:

```
<Image Height="100" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage DecodePixelWidth="100">
            <BitmapImage.UriSource>
                <PriorityBinding>
                    <Binding Path="MyModel1.ImagePath"/>
                    <Binding Path="MyModel2.ImagePath"/>
                </PriorityBinding>
            </BitmapImage.UriSource>
        </BitmapImage>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

In my viewmodel, the value of ImagePath:

```
public object ImagePath
{
    get { return new Uri("F:/myFolder/default.png", UriKind.Absolute); }
}
```

The path F:/myFolder/default.png exists. I get the error: Property 'UriSource' or property 'StreamSource' must be set. Why is this happening? Where am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you cannot initialize a `BitmapImage` if you don't have a `UriSource` or `StreamSource` immediately available.  You don't have a source immediately available because you are providing it via a `Binding`, and bindings are not available until the data context has been set and the binding has been processed, which does not happen immediately.

You will need to defer creation of the `BitmapImage` until the sources are available.  You can do this with a custom converter:

```cs
public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public ImageConverter()
    {
        this.DecodeHeight = -1;
        this.DecodeWidth = -1;
    }

    public int DecodeWidth { get; set; }
    public int DecodeHeight { get; set; }

    public object Convert(
        object value,
        Type targetType,
        object parameter,
        CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var uri = value as Uri;
        if (uri != null)
        {
            var source = new BitmapImage();
            source.BeginInit();
            source.UriSource = uri;
            if (this.DecodeWidth >= 0)
                source.DecodePixelWidth = this.DecodeWidth;
            if (this.DecodeHeight >= 0)
                source.DecodePixelHeight = this.DecodeHeight;
            source.EndInit();
            return source;
        }
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value,
        Type targetType,
        object parameter,
        CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

```xml
<Image Height="100"Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
  <Image.Source>
    <PriorityBinding>
      <Binding Path="Model1.ImagePath" Converter="{StaticResource ImageConverter}" />
      <Binding Path="Model2.ImagePath" Converter="{StaticResource ImageConverter}" />
    </PriorityBinding>
  </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

...and drop this in your resources:

```
<l:ImageConverter x:Key="ImageConverter" DecodeWidth="100" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the plain `string` file paths and let the Framework convert them to `BitmapImage` elements:

```
public string ImagePath
{
    get { return new "F:/myFolder/default.png"; }
}
```

...

```
<Image Height="100" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Image.Source>
        <PriorityBinding>
            <Binding Path="MyModel1.ImagePath"/>
            <Binding Path="MyModel2.ImagePath"/>
        </PriorityBinding>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Comment: return new "F:/myFolder/default.png"; returns error: Type expected.

Comment: I have to use BitmapImage because I want to use the DecodePixelWidth property.

Comment: Sorry, that property should have been a `string`... copy and paste error. I've updated it now.